# Dictionary out of a list in python

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary out of a list that has several similar elements. But, in the dictionary, all these similar elements must have the same key.

```
d_dict={}
lst=['A1','A2','A3','2e','2o','2m']

for element in lst:    
    if element.startswith('A'):
        d_dict[1].append(element)
    elif element.startswith('2'):
        d_dict[2].append(element)

print(d_dict)
```

My output should look like:

```
d_dict={1:['A1','A2','A3'],2:['2e','2o','2m']}
```

thanks.

Comment: How do you determine the keys in the general case?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for element in lst:
...     if element.startswith('A'):
...         d_dict[1].append(element)
...     elif element.startswith('2'):
...         d_dict[2].append(element)
... 
>>> print d_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 2: ['2e', '2o', '2m']})
```

So pretty much, with this module, your code is exactly the same. You only need to make your dictionary a type `defaultdict` so that you can have lists as values without having to create any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the lists *before* appending something to them:

```
for element in lst:
    if element.startswith('A'):
        if 1 not in d_dict: # if it is not already created
            d_dict[1] = [element] # add list with the current element
        else:
            d_dict[1].append(element)
    elif element.startswith('2'):
        if 2 not in d_dict:
            d_dict[2] = [element]
        else:
            d_dict[2].append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see in your code is that you don't initialize the sublists, so `d_dict[1]` doesn't exist. But you can avoid having to do this altogether if you use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

d_dict=defaultdict(list)
d_dict[1].extend(e for e in lst if e.startswith('A'))
d_dict[2].extend(e for e in lst if e.startswith('2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted your code to be more flexible, this will work with any strings, not just those starting with `A` and `2`. You can use the `defaultdict` class from `collections`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = ['A1','A2','A3','2e','2o','2m']
grouped = defaultdict(list)

for i in values:
    grouped[i[0]].append(i)

print(dict(grouped))
```